# How to create an alert to notify an user when some amount % of threshold reached DailyAsyncApex Executions

Tags: asynchronous, salesforce, execution, force.com

On 2 occasions in the past month, we have managed to hit our daily limit on asynchronous apex executions. Salesforce temporarily increased our limit to 425000 but it will be scaled down to 250000 in a week's time. Once we reach the limit, a lot of the SF functions will fail and this has tremendously impacted both internal staff and external customers.

So to prevent this from happening in the future, we need to create some kind of alert in Salesforce to monitor our daily asynchronous apex method executions. Our maximum daily limit is 250000. The alert will need to create a P3 helpdesk ticket and notify couple of users say USER A and USER B once it reaches 70% threshold.

Kindly advise what is possible to achieve the same

Thanks & Regards,
Harjeet

Answer (score 1):

There's a promising [Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) method but it doesn't seem to work currently ("reserved for future use"): `System.debug(Limits.getAsyncCalls() + ' / ' + Limits.getLimitAsyncCalls());`

There's an idea you can upvote: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VIFQA2 ;)

You could query `SELECT COUNT() FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ...` but that sounds like a bad idea ;)

I think your best course of action is to use SF REST API. There's a "limits" resource you can fetch. You could do it from SF itself (bad idea because if you'd schedule it to run every hour then well, of course it will contribute to the limit consumption too ;)) or from some external app that'd connect to your SF...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm

You can quickly try it out for example in workbench.developerforce.com before you decide you do want to deep dive into coding it.

[image: sample snapshot of the limits REST call]

Of course if you have control over your batch jobs, queuable, schedulable & `@future` calls you could implement some rough counter of executions in a helper object for example... won't help you much if most of the jobs are coming from managed packages though...

Got 1 more idea but it's pretty hardcore - you should be able to make a REST API call from javascript. so you could create a simple VF page (even without any apex controller), put JS callout on it, have it check every 5 mins and do something if threshold is hit... But that means IT person would have to have this page open all the time (perhaps as a home page component)... Messy :)

Comment: Thnks @eyescream for your quick response. You have provided few options above bt for all of above you have mentioned bad ideas to implement.May I know what helps me in my conditions mentioned in my question.Many thanks in advance

Comment: @eyescream-screenshot which you have posted I am aware of the same. From there only I can know how much execution limits exhausted and how much are remaining. I need a mechanism which send some kind of an alert to couple of users if Async Apex Executions reaches some threshold say when Async Apex Executions limits reaches 70% of Available limits then an alert should go to couple of persons notifying them about the same. Kindly help. Many thanks in advance

Comment: The REST API route because it's the only one that does give you some meaningful numbers, called from Apex (which will contribute to your scheduled jobs because it's also an async operation) or from another program. You could write something in whatever other language you're familiar (PHP? C#? Python?) and have it periodically fetch numbers from SF... You could host the app yourself or have it on a free Heroku node for example

Comment: Dear @eyescream thanks for your quick response. Whatever you suggested I am not aware of those. Can you please provide any link which help me to start with something or help me overcome my problem statement with very good solution. I did some Googling and couldn't find so I turned up to StackExchange. Kindly elaborate process if possible because I am very new to concept which you have suggested. Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: We're not a free code writing service, we won't give you a ready solution on a plate. If you claim you already knew about the REST call and if you don't know any other programming languages - see what you can achieve with making a HTTP callout from apex, putting it in schedulable class and sending an email or whatever when threshold is hit. There are tons of examples. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue so I created a simple JsForce script in NodeJS to monitor the call to the /limits endpoint.

You can connect a Free Monitoring service like UpTimerobot.com or PingDom.com and get an email when you find the Word "Warning" >50% or "Error" > 80%.

```
async function getSfLimits() {
try {
    //Let's login into salesforce
    const login = await conn.login(SF_USERNAME, SF_PASSWORD+SF_SECURITY_TOKEN);
    //Call the API
    const sfLimits = await conn.requestGet('/services/data/v51.0/limits');

    return sfLimits;
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

https://github.com/carlosdevia/salesforcelimits