# Notification alert for Async Apex Execution Limits

Tags: asynchronous, notifications, salesforce, force.com

I want to send an alert notification when overall organisation Async Apex Execution limit reached 70% of total limit. Say if limit is 2500 and if system already exhausted 1750 of daily Async Apex Limit out of 2500 then any alert should be send to few persons notifying that your organisation limit of Async Apex Executions have reached 70% threshold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an alert to notify an user when some amount % of threshold reached DailyAsyncApex Executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660947/how-to-create-an-alert-to-notify-an-user-when-some-amount-of-threshold-reached)

Comment: You've done zero research on your own, you expect a ready working solution on a silver plate.

Comment: No its not like that I had researched a lot..I got limit class which only deals with future limits but not about Async Apex Execution. I did wrote a class which checks future limits and if it exceeds 70% of total then an email notification will be triggered using single email messaging.

Comment: I wrote below logic inside class:myFutureLimit=Limits.getLimitFutureCalls();
        
        if(myFutureLimit == (0.25 * 250000)){ //trigger single email messaging